# How to load user control at run time, in a aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have got 5 user controls placed in some Control folder, at run time on basis of some ID I want to load user control from the Control folder to the aspx page.
Could any body tell how should I pass that ID to fix which user control to load in some div at run time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Page Init do

```
UserControl uc = new UserControl();
string ID = "1";
string userControl ="UC" + ID + ".ascx";
uc = LoadControl(userControl) as UserControl;
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc); //some place holder to place controls
```

Comment: On some drop down selection i am loading the specific user control, but i see the user control i added through above code successfully, but the data not being renderedto the page, could you tell me how to make it.